# Adobe Media Encoder CC do not work/start/load on Win8 x64

Tags: software, windows

So pretty much it. Simply clicking the .exe nothing happens, no errors, no nothing. It just simply do not work. Premiere works and when exporting video and clicking Queue simply nothing happens, AME doesn't get loaded neither, I just get back to Premiere window.

I also applied latest 7.0.1 update and nothing.

With CS6 everything worked.

Comment: Reinstall helped. Uninstalled everything together with Premiere, and installed fresh copy.

Comment: Welcome to AVP!  Please take a quick look at the [help section](http://avp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) concerning what types of questions are on-topic.  If you don't get a suitable answer here, you may have better luck at [superuser](http://www.superuser.com)

Comment: The same problem for me but on win7 x64...

Answer (score 2):

Solution #2 (as Eric Vinyard suggested):
1. Locate file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\SLCache\X19zbGNfZmVhdHVyZXNf­Xw==.slc
2. Open it with a text editor (may need to open it as an admin as this is in Program Files directory)
3. Delete everything the file contains
4. Save and close
5. Set the 'Read Only' attribute for the file: Right Mouse - Preferences. On the first page that opens for you, look for Attributes at the bottom of this page and check 'Read Only'. Close with OK.

Comment: For the curious, that apparently random looking file name is actually the [base64 encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) of "\_\_slc_features\_\_".

Answer (score 1):

Create a .bat file containing:

```
del "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\SLCache\X19zbGNfZmVhdHVyZXNfXw==.slc"
start "AME" "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Media Encoder CC\Adobe Media Encoder.exe"
```

and just run AME with it.

You could add Premiere Pro in as well so that AME get's started before Premiere Pro and all is good. Premiere will then be able to queue directly to AME.

```
del "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\SLCache\X19zbGNfZmVhdHVyZXNfXw==.slc"
start "AME" "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Media Encoder CC\Adobe Media Encoder.exe"
start "PremierePro" "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Premiere Pro CC\Adobe Premiere Pro.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you by any chance know why this should work?

Comment: I'm just guessing here but it looks like the old cache files might be invalid for a new session of Premiere and cause an error internally that simply doesn't show up for the user.

Answer (score -1):

If nothing helped you to launch AME, watch this:

Comment: Please consider adding some of the key details to this post.  If the video was to move, this answer would not provide enough to go on.